# Find the value of an XML Element in C# when an attribute is attached to that Element

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, element, xmldocument

I have the following XML document to work with.

```
<ns0:ProductQuantity>
    <ns0:Measurement>
        <ns0:MeasurementValue>8500</ns0:MeasurementValue>
        <ns0:UnitOfMeasureCode Domain="UN-Rec-20">KG</ns0:UnitOfMeasureCode>
    </ns0:Measurement>
</ns0:ProductQuantity>
```

I have yet been unable to figure out how to read the value of "KG" from this document into a string in my C# code. I have extracted other element values, but none of them have this attribute of `Domain="UN-Rec->20"` attached to them. I am using Visual Studio 2013, and an idea of how I am currently extracting other data is as follows.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);               
root = doc.DocumentElement;
prodAmt_xml[1] = root.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:MeasurementValue")[0].InnerText;
```

If anyone has any incite into this problem and a way to get these 'measurement units' I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the XML namespace into account. `ns0` isn't really part of the element name, it's a prefix that maps to a namespace (usually a URL).

Using Linq to XML and C# 6, assuming the URL for `ns0` is `http://foo.bar/`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://foo.bar/");
var unit = 
    doc.Descendants(ns + "ProductQuantity")
        .Elements(ns + "Measurement")
            .Elements(ns + "UnitOfMeasureCode")
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("Domain")?.Value == "UN-Rec->20")
            .Select(e => e.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Note that `?.` requires C# 6; if you're using an earlier version, you can also do this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://foo.bar/");
var unit = 
   (from e doc.Descendants(ns + "ProductQuantity")
              .Elements(ns + "Measurement")
              .Elements(ns + "UnitOfMeasureCode")
    let attr = e.Attribute("Domain")
    let domain = attr != null ? attr.Value : null
    where domain == "UN-Rec->20"
    select e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I do not have some of these commands to use despite using a 'LINQ' and 'XML' library reference. Is there no way to treat the "ns0:UnitOfMeasureCode" as an element name and ignore the attached attribute and namespace? I have seen some reference to the format     '.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:UnitOfMeasureCode",[@Domain="UN-Rec-20"])'   but I have yet to have it work correctly. I believe I am using c# 5.0 with .Net 4.5 if that helps.

Comment: @MBrockley you need a reference to `System.Xml.Linq.dll`. The only C# 6 feature I'm using here is `?.`. I'll send a version of the code that doesn't need it.

Comment: "Is there no way to treat the "ns0:UnitOfMeasureCode" as an element name and ignore the attached attribute and namespace?" No, that's not how XML works...